# Determine URL prior to routing in controller for asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, datatables

I am developing an asp.net core site, and I have a controller class which gets data for an api that I am using (jquery datatable).

**ClientController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GuptaAccounting.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace GuptaAccounting.Controllers
{
    //Need to add the route so server knows which path/url to go to
    [Route("api/Client")]
    //State that this is an api controller
    [ApiController]
    public class ClientController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public ClientController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                data = _db.Client.Where(Client => Client.IsConsultationClient == false).ToList()
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I need to know where I am on the site, prior to routing to "api/client" so that i can return different data in the GetAll function (returning clients where IsConsultationClient == true). How would I do this? I have already tried to use `IHttpContextAccessor` and i didn't have any luck.

**[EDIT]**

I am making an ajax call from a js file. Here is part of my code

```html
dataTable = $('#DT_load').DataTable({
        //need to make an ajax call using the api that i included
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/api/client",
            //this is a get request
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
```

Comment: Maybe [Action Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#action-filters) can help you. The `ActionExecutingContext` class contains many kinds of information about the request.

Comment: unfortunately I didn't find anything that can help me :( . Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you add some additional information in your request header? So that you can use `ActionExecutingContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers` to get these information and modify `ActionExecutingContext.ActionArguments` which will be given to the endpoint (in your case, `GetAll()`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work.

In controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[MyRouter]
public IActionResult GetAll(bool isConsultationClient = false)
{
    return Json(new
    {
        data = _db.Client
            .Where(Client => Client.IsConsultationClient == isConsultationClient).ToList()});
    }
}
```

In AttributeFilter:

```cs
public class MyRouterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers
                .TryGetValue("IsConsultationClient", out var isConsultationClient))
        {
            if (isConsultationClient== "Yes")
                context.ActionArguments.Add("isConsultationClient", true);
            else if (isConsultationClient== "No")
                context.ActionArguments.Add("isConsultationClient", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it is not working. I created another class and put in the code as you posted for MyRouterAttribute. I changed the line "if (isConsultationClient== "Yes")" to "if (isConsultationClient== true)" since it is a boolean value. I did the same for false. In my results, I am only getting clients where IsConsultationClient = false. I think this is because of "bool isConsultationClient = false" in the first piece of code that you posted. Any other suggestions/fixes?

Comment: The `bool isConsultationClient = false` code is a default value for `isConsultationClient` so it will not throw an exception when your request DOES NOT contains the "IsConsultationClient" header. Could you post your code in `MyRouterAttribute` class?